# How to use callback function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

I want to change this code to use a callback function. I would like the program to call the `ExecuteScriptForEdit` after calling `DynamicLoadScriptForEdit()`, but this code doesn't work.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  DynamicLoadScriptForEdit('/temps/F.js', function(err) {
    ExecuteScriptForEdit();
  }); //네트워크가 좋으면 상관없지만 안좋으면 동기화가 실패, 콜백으로 가야함
}

function DynamicLoad(source) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = source;
    script.onload = function() {
        //do stuff with the script 
    };
    document.head.appendChild(script);
}

function DynamicLoadScriptForEdit(source, callback) {
    DynamicLoad(source);
    OnButton('ID_Button_Test');
}
```

Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: function DynamicLoad(source) {
 var script = document.createElement('script'); 
 script.src = source;
 script.onload = function () {
  //do stuff with the script
 };
 document.head.appendChild(script); 
}
 
function DynamicLoadScriptForEdit(source, callback) {
 DynamicLoad(source);
 OnButton('ID_Button_Test');
}

Comment: @Tushar This is the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve this you can pass the function you provide to `DynamicLoadScriptForEdit()` in the `callback` parameter to the lower level functions before calling it in the `onload` handler of the script. Try this:

```
window.onload = function() {
    DynamicLoadScriptForEdit('/temps/F.js', function(err) {
        ExecuteScriptForEdit();
    });
}

function DynamicLoadScriptForEdit(source, callback) {
    DynamicLoad(source, callback); // provide callback function
    OnButton('ID_Button_Test');
}

function DynamicLoad(source, callback) { // receive callback function here
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = source;
    script.onload = function() {
        // do stuff with the script 

        callback && callback(); // call here
    };
    document.head.appendChild(script);
}
```

Comment: You save me. I'm sorry I'm not good at writing english. Thank you!! I remember you.